# How to visually present a variable of more than two letters as if it were one.How should I proceed?

Tags: output-formatting, syntax

I can't find a clear way to express my question but they say that a picture is worth a thousand words.
Attached is an image of the desired result

[image: Example]

Answer (score 7):

You could modify the formatting rules for the variables:

```
xy /: MakeBoxes[xy, StandardForm] := TagBox["xy", #&, SyntaxForm->"*"]
Δx /: MakeBoxes[Δx, StandardForm] := TagBox["Δx", #&, SyntaxForm->"*"]
```

Then:

```
Expand[(2x+Δx)^2]
Expand[(2xy+Δx)^2]
Solve[Δx+2 a x==(a+Δx)^2,x]
```

[image]

If you really want parentheses with plus as well, use `SyntaxForm->"+"` instead of `SyntaxForm->"*"`.

Comment: @ Carl Woll_great, but I don't see the difference in putting a plus sign (+), or I didn't understand your message

Comment: @BeTDa Do you want parentheses around `Δx` in the `a^2 - Δx + ..` portion of the Solve output?

Comment: @ Carl Woll ,can you give an example please

Comment: @BeTDa An example of what?

Comment: @ Carl Woll , I don't understand what you mean by this, my English is bad, I use translator.              * Do you want parentheses around Δx in the a^2 - Δx + .. portion of the Solve output*

Comment: @BeTDa Do you really want `a^2 - (Δx) + ...` or is `a^2 - Δx + ...` ok?

Comment: @ Carl Woll ,now i understand, i need the first thing you indicate

Answer (score 5):

```
xy /: MakeBoxes[xy, _] := RowBox[{"(", "xy", ")"}]
Δx /: MakeBoxes[Δx, _] := RowBox[{"(", "Δx", ")"}]
Expand[(2 x + Δx)^2]
Expand[(2 xy + Δx)^2]
Solve[Δx + 2 a x == (a + Δx)^2, x]
```

[image]